# relatedTo() only on one field?

Tags: craft3, entry, elementquery

I have a Product entry type that contains a field for Components (which are also products) and a field for Related Products (again, also Products). I want to be able to find a parent product from a Component, but using a relatedTo() gives me all the Products on which it is a Related Product as well.

Is there a way to specify which field you want to use with the relatedTo() method?

```
$product = Entry::find()->section('products')->relatedTo($component)->one();
```

Expected result = The parent product.

Actual result = A random product on which the component is a related item.

Of course, this was all working great until I just recently added the Related Products field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha. I figured it out. Leaving the answer here in case anyone else runs into the same problem:

```
$product = Entry::find()->section('products')->relatedTo([
    'element' => $component,
    'field' => 'productComponents'
])->one();
```

You can pass an object/array to the relatedTo() method as described here:

[Relations | Craft 3 Documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter)